# How do I prevent xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf() forcibly reordering the dimensions to put 'time' first?

Tags: python-xarray, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a netCDF file, `data.nc`.`ncdump -h data.nc` shows that the dimensions are:

```
dimensions:
    cell = 20480 ;
    nv = 3 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
```

In a Jupyter notebook, when I read this file in and examine it:

`data = xr.open_dataset('data.nc')`

`data`

I get the expected output of 'Dimensions: (cell: 20480, nv: 3, **time**: 12)'.

All fine so far. However, if I then save a copy of `data` as a new netCDF file:

`data.to_netcdf(path='data_copy.nc')`

`ncdump -h data_copy.nc` shows:

```
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
    cell = 20480 ;
    nv = 3 ;
```

Oddly enough, though, if I read in this copy with:

`data_copy = xr.open_dataset('data_copy.nc')`

`data_copy`

I correctly get the same 'Dimensions: (cell: 20480, nv: 3, **time**: 12)' as the original.

I thought that this might have something to do with netCDF versions, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76542356/nco-change-time-dimension-back-to-unlimited). 
`ncdump -k data.nc` shows `classic`, which seems particularly weird as the answer says "there's no way to make time unlimited and have it be the last dimension in a netCDF3 file" – but that's the precise situation with `data.nc`, a netCDF3 file with time as the unlimited last dimension. 
I have tried several format options in the [xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html), e.g. `data.to_netcdf(path='data_copy.nc', format='NETCDF4')`, but all of them still show

```
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
    cell = 20480 ;
    nv = 3 ;
```

with `ncdump`, and yet the correct order when read back in with `xr.open_dataset` and examined as Datasets. 
I've also tried specifying `engine='netcdf4'` when saving as netcdf4 and `unlimited_dims='time'`, but the dimension order of my saved copy has 'time' first no matter what when checked with `ncdump`. 
I've read every related question I can think of, but the two most frequent suggestions don't seem applicable. I don't want to reorder dimensions with `ncpdq`, because that changes those dimensions internally for each *variable*, not for the file as a whole, and I would rather prevent the problem than correct it. It also doesn't seem like a case for `xarray.Dataset.transpose()`, because the dimensions are already correct when the data is in Dataset form. 
 I've also tried reordering the dimensions of `data_copy.nc` with `ncks` as outlined [here](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/11747), but `ncks -A -v cell data_copy.nc outfile.nc` gave me:

```
ncks: ERROR nco_xtr_mk() reports user-supplied variable name 
or regular expression 'cell' is not in and/or does not match 
contents of input file
```

which I don't understand (and comes back to the issue of prevention being preferable).

Why does this dimension reordering happen when I save the Dataset as a netCDF file, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Yes, if you store your data using NETCDF3 format, only one dimension can be UNLIMITED, and it must be the outer (leftish) dimension of the variable.

Comment: ... try to use NETCDF4 format, which allows more than 1 UNLIMITED dimension, and no restriction on their order. BTW, it the 'dimension:' section it is just an enumeration of dimensions used by the variables itself, where they are been used.

Comment: @AntonioS.Cofiño, thank you for your very quick reply. I understand that in netCDF3 format only the first dimension can be unlimited, and so that is necessarily time. What I don't understand is how it is possible that the original data.nc was a classic (=netCDF3, correct?) file in which that was _not_ the case, and why saving the copy with `unlimited_dims="time", format="NETCDF4", engine="netcdf4"` still results in a file where `ncdump` shows time as the first dimension.